# Matrix expansion for $x\rightarrow0$

Tags: asymptotics, matrix-norms

Let $U$ be an $N\times N$ matrix whose entries are all equal to 1, and let B an $N\times N$ symmetric matrix whose entries are all positive. B is in general non-invertible.

I am interested in the following quantity:

$$A(x) = \|(U + xB)^{-1}\|$$

where $x$ is a positive scalar and norm can be any norm (Frobhenius, largest eigenvalue, ...). I would pick the one that is easiest to work with.

Because $U$ has all entries equal to 1, $U + xB$ is not invertible, my goal is to derive the asymptotic behavior of $A(x)$ for $x\rightarrow0$.

My guess is that $A(x)$ will go to infinity like some power of $\frac{1}{x}$. How could I proceed?

I thank you in advance.
My best regards.

Comment: I've fixed up your post, however in the future, please learn the basics of MathJax formatting.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to add that B is symmetric. How do I edit my post? Thank you

Comment: there should be an Edit button at the bottom of your post

Comment: $U+xB$ is not necessarily singular just because $U$ is a matrix of ones.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it becomes singular for x->0

Answer (score 0):

First, note that
$$
\left(U+xB\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x}U+B\right)^{-1}.
$$
Since $U=ee^{\intercal}$ where $e$ is the vector of ones, assuming $B$ is invertible, the Sherman-Morrison formula yields
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}U+B\right)^{-1}=B^{-1}-\frac{\frac{1}{x}B^{-1}UB^{-1}}{1+\frac{1}{x}e^{\intercal}B^{-1}e}=B^{-1}-\frac{B^{-1}UB^{-1}}{x+e^{\intercal}B^{-1}e}
$$
If $e^\intercal B^{-1} e \neq 0$, taking norms of both sides and applying the triangle inequality yields that the above quantity is bounded as $x\rightarrow0$.
In this case,
$$
A(x) =\Theta(x^{-1}) \qquad \text{as }x\rightarrow0.
$$
If $e^\intercal B^{-1} e = 0$, a similar argument yields
$$
A(x) =\Theta(x^{-2}) \qquad \text{as }x\rightarrow0.
$$
The different rates of convergence in the two cases are made clear in this plot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually B is non-invertible (I have just corrected my initial question accordingly). I do not know if it is relevant, but in my application B is a distance matrix, i.e. the $(i,k)$ element of B is the squared Euclidean distance between vector $x_i$ and vector $x_k$ in $R^D$, with $D<N$. Does it help?